# Нужна запятая перед союзом КАК в приведенных предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, как

1)  **Дом как у короля, слава богу… Денег как у короля!.**. [С. С. Юшкевич. Король. Пьеса в четырех действиях (1906)]

2)  **У него дом () как у короля!**

**У него глаза () как у тебя.**

3) **У них окончания как у существительных...**

Какова грамматическая основа этих предложений? Как объяснить постановку или отсутствие знаков препинания перед союзом КАК?

Comment: Во всех примерах, кроме последнего, сравнительный оборот. В последнем с.о. является частью сказуемого.

Comment: А какая разница между (2) и (3)? Структура вроде бы одинаковая.

Comment: Дом, как у Кароля ( сравнение, дом, который похож на дом короля. Сравниваются два объекта. )..

Comment: В примере (1) то же самое. Дом как у короля, слава богу… Тоже  сравниваются два объекта.

Comment: Ну я и не спорю. Я и там за запятую .

Comment: Там в составе сказуемого. Серж, вы лучше дайте ответ с расстановкой знаков и объяснением всех предложений, а то не договоримся)

Answer (score 0):

Обычные сравнительные обороты, для запятых нет никаких противопоказаний.

Comment: Лёд как зеркало. Здесь тоже сравнительный оборот, но он выполняет функцию сказуемого. "Видишь, камни самоцветные В перстеньке как жар горят"(Некрасов). Здесь оборот в роли необосбленного обстоятельства. А вот этот же оборот обособляется:  "И подлинно, как жар, червонец заиграл" (Крылов); Таких парных вариантов много. Поэтому нужен грамматический разбор предложений.